# IPv4 address 0.0.0.0 and IPv6 address ::0 are unspecified addresses that cannot be used as a target address

Tags: c#

I am trying to establish a connection to any IP on that port. Originally, I had it said to 10.0.0.7, which was the IP of another computer on my network, so I could test the client/server. However, I want it to work with any computer without having to change the IP Address to 10.0.0.7 I tried changing it to IPAddress.Any, as the name made it seem like it would accept any IP. Evidently, it didn't because now I'm getting an error. I'm confused. Below is my entire main method, which is the only method so far.

```
        TcpClient client = new TcpClient(IPAddress.Any.ToString() , 1200);
        NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();
        string messageToSend;
        byte[] messageBytes;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Type a message to send");
                messageToSend = Console.ReadLine();
                messageBytes = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(messageToSend);
                stream.Write(messageBytes, 0, messageBytes.Length);
            }
            catch
            {

            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example can't work with `IpAddress.Any`.

You have to provide the ip of the server.

A client has to connect to a server with a given IP address.

But a server can listen for any IpAddress.

Reference :

https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.net.ipaddress.any(v=vs.110).aspx